# Send variable from javascript to php and receive it back as a link for file download

Tags: javascript, php

I need do send variable from javascript to another php file to receive a link for file download.

Variable would be send from list.php:

```
<a href="javascript:FileSave(<?php $val ?>);">PDF</a>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function FileSave($fid) { 
$.post( "getfile.php", { id: $fid }) ...

... </script>
```

Link would be recieved from getfile.php:

```
<?php if (isset ($_POST['id'])) { $link = "./pdfs/vers".$_POST['id']; } ?>
```

I want it without page reload or redirect. Can I?

Answer (score 0):

If list.php and getfile.php are on same server, you can use Ajax.

In Javascript

```
function FileSave($fid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'list.php',
    data: {
      'id': $fid
    },success: function(data){
      // Your process after received data from getfile.php
    }
  });
```

In PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
  $link = "./pdfs/vers".$_POST['id'];
  echo $link;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have finally so:
  $.post( "getfile.php", { id: $fid }) 
  .done( function(data) { ...

Comment: I didn't know such approach until now. Thanks.